# FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. for update or create

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Here is my security rule in my Firebase db:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /links/{linkId} {
      allow update, create: if request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my JS using version 9 of Firebase:

```
const db = getFirestore()
await addDoc(collection(db, "links"), {
    title: 'my link title'
})
```

I'm 100% certain that I am currently signed in. Just before my `addDoc` code, this is correctly logging the current user's uid:

```
const { getAuth } = await import('firebase/auth');
console.log(getAuth().currentUser.uid)
```

Comment: Can you edit your code/repro to prove that the user is actually signed in? E.g. can you `console.log(auth.currentUser.uid)` and show the updated code and its output in the question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just updated the description to include proof of auth.

Comment: Can you show that the `currentUser` value is not null right before the `addDoc` call? It should be a single snippet of code, as it runs in your app too. Sorry to be adamant about this, but it's not common for the security rules to be wrong about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your security rule to:

```
allow update, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
```

Comment: Note to self: security rules are not 100% JS. As in, I can't use "truthy" JS expressions. Oh well. This did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: You're most welcome, it was well worth the try. Happy coding mate :)

Comment: I'm surprised about this one too @IanDavis, as I do the `request.auth` type check in RTDB all the time.